# Radius and set of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to find for the following series the radius of convergence and the set of $x\in \mathbb{R}$ in which the series converges.

1. $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}x^{n^2}}$
2. $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^n)^{3n}}(x-1)^{3n}}$

$$$$

I have done the following:

1. $a_n=\frac{n}{2^n}$ 
   $$|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|=\frac{n2^{n+1}}{(n+1)2^n}=\frac{2n}{n+1}=\frac{2}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$ 
   So, $$R=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=2$$ 
   The radius of convergence is $2$. The series converges at $|x|<2$ and diverges at $|x|>2$. 
   For $x=\pm 2$ we have the following: 
   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}(\pm 2)^{n^2}$$ 
   How could we continue?

$$$$

2. $a_n=\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^n)^{3n}}$ 
   $$\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^n)^{3n}}}=\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^n)^3}$$ 
   For $n=2k$ : $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^{2k})^3}=\frac{1}{5^3}$$ 
   For $n=2k+1$ : $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^{2k+1})^3}=\frac{1}{3^3}$$ 
   So, $\frac{1}{R}=\lim\sup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\frac{1}{3^3}$. 
   The radius of convergence is $3^3=27$. The series converges at $|x|<27$ and diverges at $|x|>27$. 
   For $x=27$ we have the following: 
   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^n)^{3n}26^{3n}}$$ How could we check if the series converges? 
   For $x=-27$ we have the following: 
   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^n)^{3n}(-28)^{3n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^n)^{3n}28^{3n}(-1)^n}$$ Is this an alternating series? Do we use here the Leibniz criterium?

$$$$

**EDIT** for 2.

$a_n=\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^n)^{3n}}$ 
$$\sqrt[3n]{|a_n|}=\sqrt[3n]{\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^n)^{3n}}}=\frac{1}{4+(-1)^n}$$ 
For $n=2k$ : $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{4+(-1)^{2k}}=\frac{1}{5}$$ 
For $n=2k+1$ : $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{4+(-1)^{2k+1}}=\frac{1}{3}$$ 
So, $\frac{1}{R}=\lim\sup\sqrt[3n]{|a_n|}=\frac{1}{3}$. 
The radius of convergence is $3$. The series converges at $|x-1|<3$ and diverges at $|x-1|>3$.

We have to check the convergenxe for $|x-1|=3 \Rightarrow x=4 \text{ and } x=-2$.

For $x=4$ we have the following: 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^n)^{3n}3^{3n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(12+3(-1)^n)^{3n}}$$ How could we check if the series converges?

For $x=-2$ we have the following: 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^n)^{3n}(-3)^{3n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4+(-1)^n)^{3n}3^{3n}(-1)^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{(12+3(-1)^n)^{3n}}$$ Is this an alternating series? Do we use here the Leibniz criterium?

Comment: Which is the radius of convergence-criterion? I got stuck right now...  @b00nheT

Comment: I am adding an answer :)

Comment: Ok!! :-) @b00nheT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be careful with both:

For the second: note that again the power series is not of the form $x^n$ but $x^{3n}$ so you need to take the third root of the convergence radius you found (do the same as I suggested for the first part, or do the substitution $y=x^3$ to get a power series in the usual form, and then switch back to $x$). Moreover the power series is not centered at $0$ but in $1$, so the interval must be shifted to $(1-r,1+r),$ where $r$ is the convergence radius.

For first one: note that it is not a usual power series, as it contains only terms of the form $x^{(n^2)}$ and not the usual $x^n$. So you better apply the radius of convergence-criterion directly, instead of looking at successive quotients, i.e. find out for which $x$ 
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{n}{2^n}x^{n^2}\right|}=\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{2}|x|^n<1\iff |x|<1$$
and then argue for the values at the boundary

Actually you can show that the radius of convergence of the second is $1$. Just Plug any $|x|>1$ inside and wee that the sequence is not a null-sequence, so the series cannot converge. For $|x|<1$ you can see that the series in absolutely convergence by bounding it with the series evaluated at $|x|=1$.

Comment: At the first case, why do we take also $x^{n^2}$ in the root? Do we not take only the coefficient?

Comment: Before I answer this question: could you confirm that the power series is in $x^{(n^2)}$ and not in $(x^n)^2=x^{2n}$?

Comment: It's the first one : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtM1D.png

Comment: I have written an edit for the second case.... Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Basically, the root test tells you that for a general series of the form 
$$\sum b_n,$$
the series converges if $\limsup \sqrt[n]{|b_n|}<1.$ Now you apply this same test to the power series, and your $b_n$ will now be $a_nx^n$. Of course as you are taking the limit over all sequences $n\to \infty$, you can also pick the sequence $n^2$, so that's why we can apply the convergence criterion for series not of the form $a_nx^n$, but then you need to take account for this in the formula.

Comment: @MaryStar: in your edit you evaluated the series at $x=\pm \frac{1}{3}$ but you should actually have evaluated it at $x=\pm 3$. To check if the series converges of diverges: just write it out as a sum of even + odd. Then at $+3$ you have a sum of a divergent series plus a convergent series, which thus is divergent. In the second $x=-3$ both series are convergent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49554/discussion-between-b00n-het-and-mary-star).